# Can I make an object to repeat in a loop?

Tags: html, jquery

My current code look like this:

```
var that = $(this).closest('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  that.next().find("[name='prod_code']").val(data[i]["prd_code"]);
  that.next().find("[name='prod_desc']").val(data[i]["prd_desc"]);
  that.next().find("[name='prod_qty']").val(data[i]["prd_qty"]);
}
```

What it does is to set the value from the array to the input inside a table.
But currently it can only set 1 row with the last element in the array.

I found out that if I add next() function repeatedly it can insert all the product in the table, but it kinda look dumb to do that manually.

My expectation of loop (I have tried but it doesn't work):

```
var that = $(this).closest('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var next = "next()";
  that.next.find("[name='prod_code']").val(data[i]["prd_code"]);
  that.next.find("[name='prod_desc']").val(data[i]["prd_desc"]);
  that.next.find("[name='prod_qty']").val(data[i]["prd_qty"]);
  next++;
}
```

Someone please point out what am I missing.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please add some of the relevant HTML to illustrate the nature of the problem please?! Also some source data might be useful

Comment: `that = that.next()`?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have the `i` index of the row which can be aligned with the index of the object within the array, then you can use `eq()` to find the `tr` by that index in order to update the form controls within it:

```js
var $rows = $('#yourTable tbody tr');

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  $rows.eq(i).find('[name="prod_code"]').val(data[i]['prd_code']);
  $rows.eq(i).find('[name="prod_desc"]').val(data[i]['prd_desc']);
  $rows.eq(i).find('[name="prod_qty"]').val(data[i]['prd_qty']);
}
```

Alternatively you could loop over the `tr` and use their index to find the object within the array:

```js
$('#yourTable tbody tr').each((i, tr) => {
  let $tr = $(tr);
  $tr.find('[name="prod_code"]').val(data[i]['prd_code']);
  $tr.find('[name="prod_desc"]').val(data[i]['prd_desc']);
  $tr.find('[name="prod_qty"]').val(data[i]['prd_qty']);      
});
```